# In clause using CTE not working

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here is my CTE/SQL statement:

```
with cte as (
    ...
)

select 1, 0, q.quadrantID, 0, '', 1
from Quadrants q
where q.quadrantID not in (select cte.quadrantID from cte)
order by quadrantID ASC
```

The Quadrants table has 6 records.

The CTE in this scenario doesn't return any records. My select should return the 6 records from Quadrants, but it doesn't. Why is that?

If I run the following statement:

```
select 1, 0, q.quadrantID, 0, '', 1
from Quadrants q
where q.quadrantID not in (5)
order by quadrantID ASC
```

It will return 5 of the 6 rows, like it's supposed to.

Comment: Can you post the query that populates cte?

Comment: Is there any particular reason you are selecting `select 1, 0, q.quadrantID, 0, '', 1` and not just `select q.quadrantID` ?

Comment: @ypercube yes, I have another query that unions this one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you aware that `NOT IN` will return incorrect results if your CTE is returning NULL in the data.

Try running this query and see the results you will get zero records

```
select 1, 0, q.quadrantID, 0, '', 1 
from Quadrants q 
where q.quadrantID not in (NULL,5) 
order by quadrantID ASC
```

You should write your query with `NOT EXISTS` read this for further info.

http://decipherinfosys.wordpress.com/2007/01/21/32/

**Edit:** I wrote your query with `NOT EXISTS` clause ,Try this

```
select 1, 0, q.quadrantID, 0, '', 1 
from Quadrants q 
where NOT EXISTS
(
SELECT 1  from cte WHERE cte.quadrantID=q.quadrantID 
)
order by quadrantID ASC
```

Comment: No, I didn't know about that... I just migrated to 2008 from 2005 and it seemed to work properly there? In any case, I will try this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
; WITH cte AS (
    ...
)

SELECT 1, 0, quadrantID, 0, '', 1
FROM 
  ( SELECT quadrantID
    FROM Quadrants q
  EXCEPT
    SELECT quadrantID
    FROM cte
  ) tmp 
ORDER BY quadrantID ASC ;
```